# PostGIS - Join rows by distance to eachother

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I currently have a table with multiple rows. I want to merge some of the rows based on a distance measurement (ideally in meters). For example: all the rows that are within 500m of each other will be joined into a single polygon, therefore reducing the number of rows in the table.

I'm not experienced with PostGIS so this query seems a bit advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You should use function [`PostGIS ST_ClusterDBSCAN`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html).